# change image width with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript, and i have a qouestion about the setAttributes of an image.
I want to change the width of an image depending on it's currently width. It must look something like this i think:

```
var curWidth=this.im.width;
if(curWidth>300)
   curWidth=300;
this.im.setAttributes
({
    src : this.inputs['src'].value,
    className: this.inputs['class'].value,
    width:curWidth
});
```

Like this it dosen't work. What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: What does `this` refer to?  Is that call to "setAttributes()" something provided by some library, or is it just wishful thinking?  What are those "inputs" values?

Comment: this must be some kind of library

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that `this.im` is an `img` element.

Many of the things you specify as attributes but then need to interact with from JavaScript are available via *reflected properties* — properties on the object that reflect the value of the attribute. So:

```
var curWidth=this.im.width;
if(curWidth>300) {   // <== Added braces for clarity; purely style
   curWidth=300;
}
this.im.src = this.inputs['src'].value;          // `src` is reflected
this.im.className = this.inputs['class'].value;  // `className` is the reflected "class" attribute
this.im.width = curWidth;                        // `width` is a property of its own
```

For setting style stuff (including width), I'd use the `style` object, so that last one would be:

```
this.im.style.width = curWidth + "px";
```

Note that style properties giving sizes must have units, just as in CSS (in this case, I've used pixels).

For any attribute that doesn't have a reflected property, use `setAttribute` to set them individually:

```
this.im.setAttribute("foo", "bar"); // Set the `foo` attribute to `bar`
```

You can find out which attributes are available as reflected properties, and what other properties there are, via the [W3C DOM specifications](http://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR) (you're looking for the [`HTMLImageElement` interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20030109/html.html#ID-17701901)).

Comment: While I was typing the answer I loaded yours. There's no better way to explain the problem(s) ;) +1

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough:

```
var imgWidth = image.width;
image.width = imgWidth > 300 ? 300 : imgWidth;
```